# SimpleLazyObject instead of User in re-usable Django app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-apps

I used user model `User` in my Django app in `filter` or `create` queries like that:

```
# FILTER queries
self_posts = (
    Post.objects
        .prefetch_related('stage')
        .filter(Q(stage__assignee__isnull=False, stage__assignee=request.user))
        .exclude(stage__slug__in=['vault', 'published'])
)

...

# CREATE one
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.editor = request.user

    post.save()
```

Then I packaged my app into re-useable Django module. As my User has several additional fields and methods compared to standard Django one, I created a proxy model. In my package it points to my local proxy model, but has access to actual "global" user, provided by main app auth system:

```
class User(UserModel):  # Proxy user model in packaged app
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("manage_authors", "Can manage authors"),
        )
    ...
```

Since that, inside my packaged app views I can't assign `request.user` directly to `User`-like fields, but still can use in filter queries.

```
(Pdb) request.user
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: koowpjcs>>

(Pdb) request.user.user
<User: John Doe>
```

So, `Post.objects.filter(foo=request.user)` will still work, but `post.editor = request.user` wiil fail:

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: koowpjcs>>": "Post.editor" must be a "User" instance.
```

1. Why it happend? Is it realated to re-usable app or with defining custom proxy model?
2. Is it correct to replace all calls of `request.user` to `request.user.user` in re-usable app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the statement `post.editor = request.user` will fail, since its how Django works with *logged-in users*

Anyway, you can directory assign the ***integer*** value as

**`post.editor_id = request.user.id`**

Comment: But it definitely falls with `Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: koowpjcs>>": "Post.editor" must be a "User" instance`. Please, note I'm using proxy model in a re-usable app.